# Microsoft azure cannot access data from sencha 2 mobile application

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure, sencha-touch-2, google-authentication

I have configured my Azure back end to only allow actions from authenticated users. I can authenticate my self using my Google account, but after authenticating I still cannot access any data on that table. I have my `Ext.azure.Authentication.login('google');` method in a button tap listener and it gets called properly and after that I ask azure if I'm authenticated. I always get authenticated successfully, but still cannot access the data.

Console complains that Azure back end says I'm trying to do unauthorized stuff, even though everything else tells me I'm authorized properly.

Answer (score 0):

When using authentication you should remember to add `useHeaderAuthentication : true` to your proxies to know that they should include authentication data to their headers.